# Man in the middle on SSH Tunnel with untrusted server

Tags: security, ssh, tunnel

I am using a linux server on the net and reverse port forwarding to connect to machines behind firewalls.

- From `Remote` I reverse forward Port 22 to `some_port` on `Middle`
- From `Home` I ssh into `user@Middle` on port `some_port`

Lets say I am careful to compare host keys and fingerprints of `Remote` and `Home`.

1. Can an attacker on `Middle` see my
   unencrypted traffic? (Well I guess
   that would be a no)
2. Can an attacker
   on `Middle` Fake the whole thing
   somehow and let me reveal my
   secrets? (keys, passphrase, stuff
   like that)
3. What it boils down to:
   How vulnerable is that setup?

Intuitively I would say, that there's not much they can do, since `Middle` does not see any unencrypted traffic, but I am still not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the tunnel is setup, a Man-in-the-Middle attack on the data path is as difficult as breaking into the encryption -- so, you are covered there.

However, the concern about MitM during connection setup (imo) may have some weight.
To cover that, I think you should use authorized keys always (for both connection setups).

These are things you will need to confirm.

1. Remote to Middle tunnel is safely established on some well-known-port '`P`' of Middle
   using authorized key of Remote.
2. Home to Middle connect is established on that port '`P`' using authorized key of Home
   (which I expect is placed in the `authorized_keys` file at Remote).

When these two are confirmed, you will not complete a Home to Remote connection over this tunnel unless Remote can validate Home key.

This **requires** that even if the Middle is compromised, the **Remote is never compromised**.
<sup>(ps: I think I need some more thought on this -- am open to comments and will correct or roll-back answer as fit)</sup>

Comment: yeah. My head hurts, too... these tunnel, reverse tunnel and auth things are never crystal clear to me.